# What does a single vertical bar mean in C

Tags: c

Someone showed me the following code snippet and asked what it meant:

```
if (!pFCT->FBMap(| ( VBQNum - 1 ) / 8 |) & (1 << (7 - ( ( VBQNum - 1 ) % 8)))))
{
    stuff
}
```

And I got stuck on the stand alone vertical bars.  I know two together mean "or" but just one, what does that mean.

Comment: Is that ASCII art or a condition!!!!!

Comment: you snippet looks invalid, (| is not legal construct

Comment: As it's been said already, it means bitwise OR. However, in your example it's used wrong, I think. It's a binary operator, so it needs two operands. It's generally used like this: `var_a | var_b`, `flags |= READABLE`, etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the input.

Comment: Note this code does compile!!!  I'm thinking based on what I see that somehow this means to take the absolute value of (VBQNum-1) / 8 and to then do an AND with the rest of the data.

Comments?

Comment: @Dale:  That code does compile on what compiler and what OS?

Comment: @Dale: This code does not compile and cannot compile as C code, unless it is just a comment. As C code, the code is syntactically invalid. If it "compiles" in your case, it means that either you are not compiling it as C or the code you posted is not what you are compiling.

Comment: There's, of course, a possibility of `FBMap` being defined as a macro, like `#define FBMap(x) some_fb_map(abs(0 x 0))`. Also, iot would take quite an effort to make it valid C, since the call to `FBMap` looks like a C++ method call. It is possible to make it valid in C as well, but nevertheless I'm wondering if it was supposed to be tagged C++.

Comment: @Dale: Brackets are mismatched. The only way it could compile is with some crazy macro definition. (Or the code itself is commented?)

Comment: @AndreyT:  The thing that looks like a member function call is legal C, and I've seen C written like that (although O-O C is generally a real mess).  I don't see any way to make that legal in C++ without a crazy macro definition.

Comment: @David Thornley: I know that it could be legal C, I already mentioned it in my comment and in my answer below.

Comment: The author writes (in a comment below) that it is *SAS* C. I could believe it being legal there. Vendor extensions, don't you just love 'em? </sarcasm>

Answer (score 17):

One bar by itself means "bitwise OR"   (as opposed to the double bar which means "Logical OR")

```
 1 | 1 == 1
 0 | 1 == 1
 1 | 0 == 1
 0 | 0 == 0
 true || true  == true
 false || true == true


 01 | 10 == 11
 01 || 10 == true
```

However, the vertical bars in your sample, as far as I can tell, are syntax errors.   It looks like the author is going for "absolute value", which would use vertical bars – in writing or pseudo-code – but not in any computer language I know of.

Comment: You meant "you're" right? (Sorry, I couldn't resist)... going back to english.stackexchange.com now...

Comment: I'd be startled if there were *no* languages that used vertical bars to mean modulus – it's been standard mathematical notation for a long time, and computing borrows loads from math – but it's sure not common.

Answer (score 16):

```
if (!pFCT->FBMap(| ( VBQNum - 1 ) / 8 |) & (1 << (7 - ( ( VBQNum - 1 ) % 8))))) { stuff }
/*              ^^^   syntax error   ^^^                               */
```

I guess whoever showed you the line in question meant absolute value

```
if (!pFCT->FBMap(abs( ( VBQNum - 1 ) / 8 )) & (1 << (7 - ( ( VBQNum - 1 ) % 8))))) { stuff }
/*              ^^^^^^                  ^^^                            */
```

---

Oh! A single vertical bar means **bitwise or**.

Answer (score 6):

Bitwise inclusive or:

> The bitwise-inclusive-OR operator compares each bit of its first operand to the corresponding bit of its second operand. If either bit is 1, the corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding result bit is set to 0.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

It is a bitwise OR.
Essentially it takes the two values and ORs each of the corresponding bits in their binary representations:

```
10010001
01001010
--------
11011011
```

If either operand's bit is a 1, the answer's bit in that place is a one. If neither are 1s, the answer has a 0 there.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [bitwise OR operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html).

Answer (score 2):

Dale said he knew it meant "or" with two operands.  His question is what it means when used as a unary operator.  Short answer is that it doesn't mean anything in C/C++.

In some languages (like Verilog for coding hardware) this is an or-reduction, which result in a 1 if any bit is one.

So I think this is a syntax error unless the is something funny going on overloading the parentheses that I can't get my head around.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid C, unless put in a specific (and quite artificial) context. Operator `|` is a binary operator. It is a bitwise-or, as you seem to know already. By itself, it cannot be used the way it is used in your code.

If one wanted to force this code to compile as C code, one'd probably have to define `FBMap` as a macro. Something like

```
#define FBMap(x) something_else(abs(0 x 0))
```

thus trying to emulate the mathematical "absolute value" operator `| |`. Your call will expand into

```
pFCT->something_else(abs(0 | ( VBQNum - 1 ) / 8 | 0))
```

thus making the application of `|` operator valid.

But even after that you'd need `something_else` to be a function pointer in that `*pFCT` struct, since the call looks awfully as a C++ method call. Your question is tagged C, so the only way to make it work in C is to introduce a function pointer member into the struct.

Comment: Fine.  The code does compile.  I did make a typo when I entered it.  It should have been:

Comment: if (!(pFCT->FBMap(| ( VBQNum - 1 ) / 8 |) & (1 << (7 - ( ( VBQNum - 1 ) % 8)))))
{
  stuff
}

Comment: This sure seems like it's trying to do an ABS on the value of VBQNum - 1 / 8.  FYI, I was just told this is SAS C.

Comment: At the first sight, SAS C docs don't seem to suggest anything as weird.