# What is "|" in C function?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm learning OpenGL and I see some function like this

```
function(parameter1 | parameter2);
```

I never see "|" before, what does it means?

Thanks.

Comment: It's the bitwise or.

Comment: I understand that searching for "|" doesn't work, but searching for "c vertical bar" brings up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865486/what-does-a-single-vertical-bar-mean-in-c, which while not the same question, does have answers that also answer your question.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly reasonable question.  Even if you understand that | means "bitwise OR," some of the use cases for bitwise OR, especially when combining flags together, are not at all obvious.

Comment: @templatetypedef One can still google "operators in C" in worst case...

Comment: this is quite strange for me, I usually pass an int, float bool and so on as a parameter but I never pass something like this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Alexandry Barbarosie pointed out, this is the bitwise OR operator.  You sometimes see this operator used this way to combine multiple different options as a single parameter to a function.  If you have many different constants, each of which is a different power of two, you can combine those constants together into a single constant by OR-ing all of them together in a way that lets the function decode which options were chosen.  For example, instead of writing

```
int function(bool wantOption1, bool wantOption2, /* etc. */);
```

You can write

```
const int WANT_OPTION_1 = 1;
const int WANT_OPTION_2 = 2;
const int WANT_OPTION_3 = 4;
const int WANT_OPTION_4 = 8;
/* ... */
```

And then define the function as

```
int function(int options);
```

You could then call the function by writing

```
function(WANT_OPTION_1 | WANT_OPTION_3);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

That is bitwise OR.
[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators) is a list of all operators in C.

Answer (score 3):

`|` is the "bitwise or" operator. It takes each bit in the two numbers and returns a number where the corresponding bit is on if it is on in either of the two numbers, e.g.:

```
00001111 = 15
01010101 = 82
--------
01011111 = 95
```

Compare with `&`, bitwise and - bit is on only if it is on in both numbers:

```
00001111
01010101
--------
00000101 = 6
```

and `^`, the bitwise xor - each bit is on if it is on in one number but not the other:

```
00001111
01010101
--------
01011010 = 90
```